# How to avoid year and second part from TIMESTAMP in oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle, timestamp

I want to avoid year and second part from TIMESTAMP in oracle. For eg. I have a field to enter a arrival time and I have another field to enter arrival date. I want to enter just 6:35 PM while entering the arrival time not the whole '2013-12-13 6:35' in my table. How can I do that?

```
     **Sample of my input**

     Arrival Date  Arrival Time

     2013-12-23    6:35 PM
```

Can anyone help me please?

Comment: to_char() to any format you require should be your answer(to_char(arrival_date,'MM-DD')). But still, It would be better, if you make your question more clear.

Comment: The technical term is "format date".

Comment: While entering arrival time, I want to directly enter the 6:35 PM. Can you help me?

Answer (score 1):

```
select to_char(systimestamp,'YYYY-MM-DD') from dual;
select to_char(systimestamp,'hh:mi:ss') from dual;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select to_char(arrival_date,'YYYY-MM-DD'),
       to_char(arrival_time,'HH:MI AM')
from dual;
```

Replace `sysdate` with your required date column.!

**on insert**

```
 set arrival_date_str as String '2013-12-22' and arrival_time_str as '06:35 PM'

insert into my_table
(arrival_date,arrival_time)
values
(
   to_date(:arrival_date_str,'YYYY-MM-DD'),
   to_date(:arrival_date_str||' '||:arrival_time_str,'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI AM')
);
```

inside table it could be saved with the data as "date of insert" and time as "06:35:00 PM"
obviously it could go wrong, so obviusoly u can use the above.

Actually, you should have used one column arrival_date, for both date and time. Can you please consider that.

Comment: While entering arrival time, I want to directly enter the 6:35 PM not he whole part of TIMESTAMP. Can you help me?

Comment: Your answer looks quite confusing!!I want to store more than 20 records. I can'tt go on useing set for each one!!

Comment: your requirement is that way, problem is there is no datatype to store just the time. only with date we can. Also `set` I mean is.. either paste it directly, or use as bind variable.

Comment: also consider having one string concatenating both date and time.. and insert into both columns.. using `to_date('2013-12-22 06:35 PM','YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI AM')`

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to use `DATE` datatype if you don't need extra precision (like milliseconds). And better choice would be store both date and time part in one database column. To retrieve it and show in UI you have to use (for date and time part respectively):

```
to_char(your_time_column,'YYYY-MM-DD')
to_char(your_date_column,'HH:MI')
```

To store entered in UI values to database you have to do reverse operation:

```
to_date(UI_date_part || ' ' || UI_time_part, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI')
```

If separate database columns are mandatory then in inserts you can use the above conversion functions:

```
insert into my_table(date_part_column, time_part_column)
 values(to_timestamp('your_date_here', 'YYYY-MM-DD'),
        to_timestamp('your_time_here', 'HH:MI'));
```

Comment: To have separate column for to enter arrival date and time is must. I just want to enter time(eg. 6:35 PM in arrival time not the whole '2013-12-12 6:35' of TIMESTAMP. Can you help me please.

Comment: @user3127109 What type of UI you use? Where do you enter it?

Comment: I am new to oracle. I am using SQLPLUS prompt to do all my queris. So it just difficult to enter the whole part of TIMESTAMP. So I would like to avoid year and millisecond from TIMESTAMP while inserting the data.

Comment: @user3127109 In inserts you can use above conversion functions to enter only date or time part. I will update my answer.

Comment: @YaroslavShabalin , you close to mine, but I made this mistake too. we cant just insert time, as the date defaults to today's date.. so we have to give the date also!!! Please see mine!